# Is completeness necessary? X separable iff weak* topology on closed unit ball of dual is metrizable.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

First some references:

- [M] Megginson - An Introduction to Banach Space Theory
- [D] Denkowski, Migórski, Papageorgiou, Socrates - An Introduction to Nonlinear Analysis
- [B] Brezis - Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations
- [DS] Dunford and Schwartz - Linear Operators Part I: General Theory

The following theorem appears in [M, p.231], [D, p.305], [B, p.74], [DS, p.426].  I'm sure it appears elsewhere too.

**Theorem.** Let $X$ be a Banach space. Then $X$ is separable iff the closed unit ball of $X^*$ is metrizable in the weak* topology (inherited from X*).

However, [M] only assumes $X$ is a normed space, not a Banach space. I've been through the proofs, and I can't see where completeness is being used.

**Question 1.** Is completeness of $X$ really necessary?

There is also a closely related theorem that appears in [D, p.305], [B, p.74], [DS, p.426]:

**Theorem.** Let $X$ be a Banach space. Then $X^{*}$ is separable iff the closed unit ball of $X$ is metrizable in the weak topology (inherited from X).

**Question 2.** Is completeness of $X$ really necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, in both caes. The dual does not "see" if $X$ is complete or not; the dual of a space and of its completion is the same. And separability and metrizability pass to subsets, so $X$ is separable/metrizable if and only if $\overline X$ is.

Comment: I forgot that the dual of a dense subspace is isometrically isomorphic to the dual of the original space.

Comment: I would say it is equal, more than isometrically isomorphic. It's just that by taking the completion you cannot introduce any new functionals.

Comment: But the weak$^*$ topology sees the completion: $\sigma(X^*,X)$ is strictly coarser than $\sigma(X^*,\tilde X)$.

Comment: @Jochen Good point. I noticed that if the Uniform Boundedness Principle holds for $X$ (it does hold for some incomplete spaces), then any net in $X^{*}$ converging to $0$ with  $\sigma(X^{*},X)$ will converge to $0$ with $\sigma(X^{*},\tilde{X})$,so the two weak* typologies are the same. So we must consider $X$ that does not have UBP.

Comment: But on the dual unter ball the weak topologies coincide: The ball is $\sigma(X^*,\tilde X) $-compact and hence the other weak topology can't be strictly coarser.

Comment: *unit ball* of course. With the device I am using now, I can't edit my comment

Comment: @Jochen Of course you are right. I'm not sure what $\sigma(X*,\tilde{X})$-compactness of the ball has to do with it though. In fact, the two weak* topologies will agree on any bounded subset of $X*$. Could you please explain your thinking?

Comment: @Jochen Here's my thinking: Suppose $(x_{\alpha})$ is a net in $X^{*}$ that converges in the topology $\sigma(X^{*},X)$ to a point $x_0$. Then $(x_{\alpha}-x_0,x) \to 0$ for every $x \in X$. Consider any $\tilde{x}$ in $\tilde{X}$. By density, we can find $x$ in $X$ such that $\|x-\tilde{x}\|$ is as small as we want. Note $|(x_{\alpha}-x_0,\tilde{x})| \leq |(x_{\alpha}-x_0,x)| + \| x_{\alpha}-x_0 \| \| x-\tilde{x} \|$. So if $(x_{\alpha})$ is a __bounded__ net, it will converge in the topology $\sigma(X^{*},\tilde{X})$.

Comment: @Jochen So, in a bounded subspace of $X^{*}$, every $\sigma(X^{*},X)$-convergent net will be a $\sigma(X^{*},\tilde{X})$-convergent net, hence the subspace $\sigma(X^{*},X)$ topology will contain the subspace $\sigma(X^{*},\tilde{X})$ topology.

Comment: For future readers: See pp. 120 of Measure Theory and Functional Analysis by Nik Weaver for a nice discussion of the weak* topology when you are working with a dense subspace of a norm. See p.121 for a slick proof of Theorem 1 in this question. Don't miss the discussion that follows the proof.

Comment: You need not touch nets or filters or neighbourhoods: on a compact Hausdorff space there is no strictly coarser Hausdorff topology.